# Set comment to a file / folder using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I am missing something here to add a comment to a file / folder.

Please help me to figure the missing thing out:

```
tell application "Finder"

    set filePath to "Macintosh HD:Users:anoopvaidya:Desktop:2.png"
    if exists file filePath then
        --display alert "file:" & filePath
        set comment of filePath to "hi boy"
    end if

end tell
```

It throws the following error:

Comment: You could add the `file` label before `filePath` or declare `filePath` as `alias "Macintosh HD:Users:anoopvaidya:Desktop:2.png"`.  The `file` label is obsolet then and it works with folders too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set comment of (filePath as alias) to "hi boy"
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, it worked. :) Now I am gonna implement same thing wrapped in Objective-c to complete [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548752/how-to-add-comments-in-a-file-and-or-directory-programmatically)