# MDItem Class In Xamarin

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to read comment field from file. 
[image]

Found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711066/how-to-read-file-comment-field) about how to do it, but can't find `MDItem` corresponding class in `Xamarin`.

Any ideas where to find it or what to use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the  `CoreServices` are not wrapped within the current `Xamarin.Mac`
(Version: 2.10.0.57).

Most of them pass `CFxxxx`-based references around, so they are easy to wrap and implement via some Interop calls.

#### Finder-based File comment

[image]

#### Code Example:

```
var fileURL = NSUrl.FromString("/Users/sushi/Desktop/DFeedback_FeedBack.png");
var mMDItemRef = MDItemCreateWithURL(IntPtr.Zero, fileURL.Handle);

var mCFTypeRef = MDItemCopyAttribute(mMDItemRef, new CFString("kMDItemFinderComment").Handle);
var finderComment = NSString.FromHandle(mCFTypeRef);
Console.WriteLine(finderComment);
```

**Note:** The interop calls should be tested for null in production code, see return signature comments in header file.

#### Application Output:

```
StackOverflow
```

#### Interop setup:

```
// @function MDItemCreateWithURL
// Returns an metadata item for the given path.
// @param allocator The CFAllocator which should be used to allocate
// memory for the query and its sub-storage.This
// parameter may be NULL in which case the current default
// CFAllocator is used.
// @param url A url to the file for which to create the MDItem.
// [[Currently, the file must exist.MDItemRefs may or
// may not be uniqued.Use CFEqual() to compare them.]]
// @result An MDItemRef, or NULL on failure.

//MD_EXPORT MDItemRef MDItemCreateWithURL(CFAllocatorRef allocator, CFURLRef url) AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6_AND_LATER;
[DllImport(Constants.CoreServicesLibrary)]
extern static /* MDItemRef */ IntPtr MDItemCreateWithURL(/* CFAllocatorRef __nullable */ IntPtr allocator, /* CFURLRef */ IntPtr inURL);

//@function MDItemCopyAttribute
//Returns the value of the given attribute for the item.
//@param item The item to be interrogated.
//@param name The name of the desired attribute.
//@result A CFTypeRef, or NULL on failure, or if the attribute
//does not exist, of if the attribute is not readable.

//MD_EXPORT CFTypeRef MDItemCopyAttribute(MDItemRef item, CFStringRef name) MD_AVAIL;
[DllImport(Constants.CoreServicesLibrary)]
extern static /* CFTypeRef */ IntPtr MDItemCopyAttribute(/* MDItemRef */ IntPtr item, /* CFStringRef */ IntPtr name);
```

#### Xcode Obj-C Header Reference:

```
MDItem.h
```

Local Xcode Ref:: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Headers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll test it out soon and get back with the result.

Comment: I have tested it too, here is the only problem, sometimes it return old comment, maybe it cached values or somehow. I have moved item + changed comment while moving -> put back and get comment , the old comment was returned. any idea?

Comment: @Nininea I have never seen an old comment return. If the comment is saved/commit via Finder or programmatically then calling `MDItemCreateWithURL` and then `MDItemCopyAttribute` should always return the "new" comment. Make sure that you are calling `MDItemCreateWithURL` each time and reusing an existing reference.

Comment: @SushiHangover I still have the problem, I described above. I think that "mCFTypeRef" is not release , and somehow uses cashed value :/ I found the native example : https://github.com/danielpunkass/iMediaLegacy/blob/master/NSURL%2BiMedia.m

Comment: @SushiHangover can you check please following link : https://github.com/xamarin/mac-samples

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @SushiHangover this demo project show the bug I was talking about

Comment: sorry,  it was wrong link . here it is : https://github.com/Nininea/Xamarin.mac-File-Comment-